# Sort by a array element (document) field - MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

This is the concerned part from the schema

`

```
var CandidateSchema = new Schema({
calculateScore:[{
jobname:{type:Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Job'}
,Score:{type:Number,default:0}
}]
})
```

`

A candidate can apply to multiple jobs and get scored differently for different jobs. I want to sort the candidates depending on the specific job's Score. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable `objectId` holds the `ObjectId` of the referred `Job`, you can aggregate the records to get the records `sorted` by the score of that particular `Job`.

Since the stage operator `$project` does not support the `$elemeMatch` operation, we cannot use it to directly get the Job sub document that we want and sort based on it.

- `$project` a separate `field` named `temp_score` to have a copy of the original `calculateScore` array.
- `$redact` other sub documents from `calculateScore` other than whose `jobname` contains the
  `id` we are looking for. Now `calculateScore` will contain only one
  element in the array, i.e the element whose `jobname` is the `id`
  that we have specified.
- Based on this sub document's score `sort` the records in `descending`
  order.
- Once the `sorting` is done, project our original `calculatescore`
  field, which is in `temp_score`.

The code:

```
var objectId = ObjectId("ObjectId of the referred Job"); // Needs to be fetched 
                                                       // from the Job collection.
model.aggregate(
{$project:{"temp_score":{"level":{$literal:1},
                         "calculateScore":"$calculateScore"},
           "calculateScore":1}},
{$redact:{$cond:[
                 {$and:[
                        {$eq:[{$ifNull:["$jobname",objectId]},objectId]},
                        {$ne:["$level",1]}
                       ]
                 },
                 "$$DESCEND",
                  {$cond:[{$eq:["$level",1]},
                          "$$KEEP","$$PRUNE"]}]}},
{$sort:{"calculateScore.Score":-1}},
{$project:{"_id":1,
           "calculateScore":"$temp_score.calculateScore"}},
function(err,res)
{
    console.log(res);
}
);
```